# What should be the new angular 2 code to replace import { Control } from '@angular/common'

Tags: angular

In Angular2 RC5, we use

```
import { Control } from '@angular/common'
```

for our validators.

In the newest updated version, this is no longer working and I can't find the right code. Anyone can help with what the new import statement should be?

The code is used in the below:

```
import { Control } from '@angular/common';

export class BasicValidators{
    static email(control: Control){
        var regEx = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
        var valid = regEx.test(control.value);
        return valid ? null : { email: true };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`FormControl`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/FormControl-class.html) or [`AbstractControl`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/AbstractControl-class.html) (super class of `FormControl`) from `'@angular/forms'`